# Intersection of a Line and a Rectangle

Tags: geometry

Can anybody tell me how to calculate the intersection point of a line and a rectangle in a way that a **programmer can understand**?

I have these types in my program and I need to pass them into a function which will return their intersection point.

```
type Point = { X : float; Y : float; Z : float }
type Line = { A : Point; B : Point }
type Rectangle = { A : Point; B : Point; C : Point; D : Point }

let findIntersection line rectangle = //...
```

Am I defining the rectangle the correct way? Do I only need the bottom left and top right points of the rectangle?

Comment: The "plane" is a square (defined by the four corners) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes it will be used in a triangle rasterizer, I need to create a line between the camera point and the points of the triangles, then see where they intersect on the "screen" plane. So I can actually draw them.

Comment: A plane has infinite extent. What you have sounds like a rectangle. The ends of its diagonal do not specify it uniquely without additional assumptions about its orientation.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for clearing that up for me, I'll change the question.

Comment: Three points suffice, or one point and two vectors that represent adjacent sides. The latter eliminates the possibility of presenting a set of vertices that aren’t actually coplanar.